# Getting fortran runtime error: end of the file

Tags: fortran, eof

I am trying to read a file using the following code and it gives the end of the file error

```
real u,v,rs,rd
open (10,file='AD02.txt',status='old')
open(12,file='AD02_1.txt',status='unknown')
    pi=atan(1.0e00)*4.0
rad=pi/180.0


    100 read(10,*,end=98)u,v


    rs=sqrt((u*u)+(v*v))
if (v.eq.0.) then
    if (u.gt.0)then
    rd = 90
    else
    rd=270
    endif
    go to 101
end if
  rd=(atan(u/v))/rad
  if((u.ge.0.).and.(v.lt.0.))
 +     rd=rd+180.
  if((u.lt.0.).and.(v.lt.0.))
 +     rd=rd+180.
  if((u.lt.0.).and.(v.ge.0.))
 +     rd=rd+360.
  if((u.eq.0.).and.(v.eq.0.))
 +     rd=0.
 101      rd=rd+180.0
  if(rd.ge.360.0) rd=rd-360.0

 c  write(12,*)rs,rd
    write(12,*)u,v,rs,rd
 goto 100
 98   close(10) 
 99   close(11)
stop
end
```

It gives end of the file error

SAMPLE INPUT:

```
1/1/2017    20:00     -2    -2.7        3.360059523 36.45608472
1/1/2017    21:00   -1.71   -2.74       3.229814236 31.89269113       
1/1/2017    22:00   -1.04   -3.48       3.632079294 16.5559465
1/1/2017    23:00   -0.67   -4.09       4.144514447 9.216650926
1/2/2017    0:00    -0.73   -4.51       4.568697845 9.107662714
1/2/2017    2:00    -1.04   -5.35       5.450146787 10.91495543
```

Upto n number of values

Please help me resolve this

Comment: Where do you get the EOF message? Looks a bit to me that you want to read ' -2    -2.7 ' into `u` and `v` but get stuck at the date so, you probably need a format to skip the date and time.

Comment: There is got to be a simpler way to do this with just a while loop. Also, see if you can `write(*,*) u,v ` after `read` to see how far it gets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @albert suggests, the date is the problem. Not only does your READ pretend the date (and time) isn't there, but a slash in list-directed input terminates the read. You want to use an explicit format - the following works:

```
100    read (10,'(T18,2F8.2)',end=98) u,v
```

I will also comment that you should NOT be coding in fixed-form source, and if you do and paste code here, you have to be aware of column positions. I had to do extensive editing of your code to get it to compile.